# Getting "WARNING: Augmenter should be applied to the instances of @Augmentable classes or previously augmented instances only"

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The below function to convert  a csv file to Excel was working fine till recently now I get a warning message.

> warning Feb 11, 2016 8:52:00 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter
>   extractRemoteWebDriver WARNING: Augmenter should be applied to the
>   instances of @Augmentable classes or previously augmented instances
>   only Feb 11, 2016 8:52:00 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter
>   extractRemoteWebDriver WARNING: Augmenter should be applied to the
>   instances of @Augmentable classes or previously augmented instances
>   only

And My automation test case fails with out converting the csv to excel.

I did try doing debugging by putting the Sys out statement. In try block 1 is printed but the next sys out `"csvFileAddress in TRY block 2"` does not prints so I believ there is something wrong with this lines.

```
XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("sheet1");


public void csvToXLSX(String csvFileAddress, String xlsxFileAddress) 
    {   
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("In TRY block 1");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("sheet1");
            System.out.println("csvFileAddress in TRY block 2");
            String currentLine=null;
            int RowNum=0;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileAddress));
            System.out.println("in TRY block 3");

            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                System.out.println("In while loop");

                String str[] = currentLine.split(",");
                XSSFRow currentRow=sheet.createRow(RowNum);
                for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
                    currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(str[i]);
                RowNum++;
            }

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =  new FileOutputStream(xlsxFileAddress);
            workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
            report.addReportStep("Converting CSV to Excel" , "Conversion successfull", StepResult.PASS);
        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            report.addReportStep("Converting CSV to Excel" , "Conversion unsuccessfull", StepResult.FAIL);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage()+"Exception in try");
        }
    }
```

Please suggest what's wrong